# browser anomaly causing css generated heading tags to be displayed wrong

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

I Have the following perplexing **css /browser** related (I assume) error that causes the H3 tags to be displayed incorrectly in Google Chrome, but correctly in Internet Explorer - this has never happened before. It displays fine in Internet Explorer (but the H1 tag is messed up there), but in Google Chrome, the h3 tag is white.

The main.css is shown below and you will see that the H3 tag is defined #000 (black), - this shows up fine when the site is opened in IE but is white in Google Chrome.

**Main CSS Code**

https://repl.it/Js8F/0

Highlight (above) over the blank white spaces to see the H3 tag headings.

Is anyone able to shed any light on why this might be happening and help please? If this indeed some browser related css issue, it would be of huge help to other users.

**Update**: this is the additional code on the php page that is in question:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Css -->
<link href="bootstrap-assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Style -->
<link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="plugins/Lightbox/dist/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="plugins/Icons/et-line-font/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="plugins/animate.css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/expanding-list.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/expanding-list.js"></script>
<!-- Icons Font -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

There is a stackoverflow previous answer which suggests a fix for a similar problem as follows:

```
<link href="/css/dropit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

..but I cannot seem to see where this would fit in with my code

Comment: <link> goes in the <head> </head> tag in HTML